# How to print just value to label from textbox in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a name generator, and want to add functionality to add new names and surnames to database, but when I'm trying to print values added after running program, I got whole *path*. For example: I want to add name *John*. When generator picks *John* it's printing `Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text:John` instead of just *name*. How can I fix this? Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NameGen
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Generate gen = new Generate();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StartGenerate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        lblWynik.Text = Generate.NameGen() + " " + Generate.SurnameGen();
        Console.WriteLine("Generating: " + lblWynik.Text);
    }

    private void AddName(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Generate.LName.Add(NameBox.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Adding new name to index " + NameBox);
        NameBox.Clear();
    }

    private void AddSurname(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        Generate.LSurname.Add(SurnameBox.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Adding new surname to index " + SurnameBox);
        SurnameBox.Clear();
    }
}

public class Generate
{
    static string[] Name = new string[] { "Hank", "Terrence", "Darin", "Alf" };
    static string[] Surname = new string[] { "Cooper", "Trump", "Białkov", "Obama" };

    public static List<string> LName = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> LSurname = new List<string>();
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static string NameGen()
    {
        LName.AddRange(Name);
        int NameIndex = random.Next(LName.Count);
        return LName[NameIndex];
    }

    public static string SurnameGen()
    {
        LSurname.AddRange(Surname);
        int NameIndex = random.Next(LSurname.Count);
        return LSurname[NameIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Text` property of `TextBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of a `TextBox` you should use [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `TextBox`. For example: `Generate.LName.Add(NameBox.Text);`

Now you are using `ToString` method of `TextBox` which returns the type name and the text.

Comment: Thank you @Reza that was very helpful, as can i ask you one more thing. Why when i'm generating names i got more frequently names/surnames from these 4 predefinied, than added to base? I mean when i add one index, and generating i got this added index one per 4example 40 attempts?

Comment: About your other question probably I can't get what you mean :)

Comment: I got 4 predefinied values per name array, and surname array, well i can generate without adding any new values inside app. When i'm adding one value to name and generating this(i use additional console to log everything inside app) i got [1-30] generated indexes are from this predefined arrays and then one value is from this added inside app. I guess it's not a pseudo generator problem, but my algorithm, and i can't figure out what's wrong :?